# Constrain generic to be a nullable type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm looking for sample usage something like this:

```
Foo<string> stringFoo = new Foo<string>("The answer is");
Foo<int> intFoo = new Foo<int>(42);
// The Value of intFoo & stringFoo are strongly typed
stringFoo.Nullify();
intFoo.Nullify();
if (stringFoo == null && intFoo == null)
   MessageBox.Show("Both are null);
```

Given this class Foo, I can auto-wrap T into a nullable:

```
public class Foo1<T>
   where T : struct
{
   private T? _value;

   public Foo(T? initValue)
   {
      _value = initValue;
   }

   public T? Value { get { return _value; } }

   public void Nullify { _value = null; }

}
```

This works for primitives, but not with String or other classes.

Next flavor works for strings, but not primitives:

```
public class Foo2<T>
{
   private T _value;

   public Foo(T initValue)
   {
      _value = initValue;
   }

   public T Value { get { return _value; } }

   public void Nullify { _value = default(T); }

}
```

I could use `Nullable<int>` for Foo2 and the code would work like this:

```
Foo2<int?> intFoo = new Foo<int?>(42);
```

But this is error prone because it fails for Foo2.  If I could constrain T to be types that support nullability then that would be fine.

**So after all of that, is there any way to constrain T to be a nullable type?**

Some additional notes:  .NET 4.0, VS2010.  And I did find one similar question to this on here, but without a succesful answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might be able to make the constructor of `Foo<T>` internal, and require that new instances can only be created through a factory class:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    private T value;
    internal Foo(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void Nullify()
    {
        this.value = default(T);
    }

    public T Value { get { return this.value; } }
}

public class Foo
{
    public static Foo<T> Create<T>(T value) where T : class
    {
        return new Foo<T>(value);
    }

    public static Foo<T?> Create<T>(T? value) where T : struct
    {
        return new Foo<T?>(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  In real life Foo is more complex and is automatically created by a framework.  I'll need to see if there is a way to hook/customize the way objects are created to make this approach feasible.

Comment: Accepted, as it gives the least surprise to the internal customer of the library (design/compile time vs runtime).  But the test used by @JonSkeet was great too!

Answer (score 21):

There's no constraint you can apply for this, but you *can* test for it at execution time:

```
if (default(T) != null)
{
    throw new SomeAppropriateException(typeof(T) + " is not a nullable type");
}
```

You could even put that into a static constructor, which would make sure it only executed *once* per constructed type - and anyone trying to use `Foo<int>` anywhere would have a hard time ignoring the `TypeInitializerException`. That's not terribly friendly for a *public* API, but I think it's reasonable for an internal one.

EDIT: There is one *horrible* way of making it harder to create instances of `Foo<int>`... you could use the [ghastly code in this blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround) (using overload resolution rules along with default parameters and a couple of constrained generic types) and mark the overload which aims at a non-nullable value type as obsolete with an error. That way, `Foo<int>` would still be a valid type, but you'd be hard-pressed to create an instance of it. I'm not going to recommend that you do this though...

Comment: @NikolayKhil: The comment you're replying to here is gone, but the code in this answer *will* work for `int?`, because the nullity check "does the right thing" for nullable type arguments.

Comment: Am I wrong or nullable types are all structs? I mean there's no constraint for "nullable types" but there's a constraint for struct. But I've done my own test and if, if you give a T : struct constraint to some generic parameter, later you can't use a nullable type as generic argument. For example, X<int?> won't work with this constraint.

Comment: Obviously this is because int? is Nullable<int> and Nullable is a reference type, but maybe .NET devteam could made some kind of syntactic sugar to allows this use case

Comment: I had intended to move the real life, non trivial Foo into a library that is used on similar projects within my company.  So it's not end-customer facing, but it is "internal-customer" facing.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - `Nullable<T>` is a struct.

Comment: The link in the answer appears to be broken. I think http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround/ is the article it pointed at.

Answer (score -1):

I don't like it as much as the syntax of Foo1, but here is Foo3:

```
public class Foo3<T>
   where T : struct
{

   private T _value;
   private T _nullValue;

   public Foo3(T initValue)
       : this(initValue, default(T))
   {
   }

   public Foo3(T initValue, T nullValue)
   {
      _value = initValue;
      _nullValue = nullValue;
   }

   public T Value { get { return _value; } }

    public bool IsNull
    {
        get 
        {
           return object.Equals(_value, _nullValue);
        }
    }

    public void Nullify() { _value = _nullValue; }

}
```

And then my usage becomes:

```
Foo3<string> stringFoo = new Foo<string>("The answer is");
Foo3<int> intFoo = new Foo<int>(42, int.MinValue);
stringFoo.Nullify();
intFoo.Nullify();
if (stringFoo.IsNull && intFoo.IsNull)
   MessageBox.Show("Both are null);
```

This is still error prone because getting the Value property of Foo3 (and Foo2) is not straightforward.  Foo1 was the best because automatically wrapped the Value will null support.

I might just need ValueTypeFoo and ObjectFoo and deal with two versons.